# How to decode input field from transaction in Golang?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

I have the abi and the input data as shown here https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-input-data-decoder/example/ I want to get the output. How can I do this in Golang?

Comment: did you figure it out? I got the same problem, there is nothing clear around there

Comment: Do you want to make a contract call and decode the output bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I share a [Parse Transcation Gists](https://gist.github.com/crazygit/9279a3b26461d7cb03e807a6362ec855).

Include decode input data and output data, It may help you.